# Place images in two-column article

Tags: multicol

I have a 2 column article in the revtex format and I simply want to choose the column (left or right) where to place my figure.
Is there a simple way to do that by adding a command to the following I have written:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{c_13}
\caption{stuff.}
\label{fig:c_13}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I don't know of any command to select the column in which a figure (or any float) is placed.  Instead, you can place the input for the figure in a location in the source file where you are certain that there is sufficient space in that column (if you want it in the same column) or *before* the beginning of the next column.  Always place figure (float) input at a paragraph break for best control over its placement.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the suggestion! So if I want to put the figure on the right column, I should place the figure roughly immediately before the text starts to occupy the right column itself?

Comment: If a figure is wanted in the right column, it can be input anywhere *after* the space still available in the left column is not sufficient to place the figure there.  Remember that placement at a paragraph break (after the blank line) is easiest to control.